# selenium + nodejs + nightwatchjs and phantomjs for pdf printing after logged in

Tags: node.js, selenium, phantomjs, nightwatch.js

I'm  still new with selenium and nodejs so please help me out here...

I have already set up the code for logging in into a site with nodejs
after successfully logged in, i have to print a page to pdf with phantom.js

```
browser.waitForElementPresent('#username', 1000, function() {
    browser.setValue('#username', 'some_username');
    browser.setValue('#password', 'some_password');
    browser.click('input[type="button"]');

    browser.waitForElementPresent('#agreeCB1', 15000, function() {
        browser.click('#agreeCB1');

        var phantom = require('phantom');       
        phantom.create().then(function(ph) {
        ph.paperSize = {
            format: 'A4'
        };
        ph.createPage().then(function(page) {
         page.open("https://www.example.com/myaccount").then(function(status) {
            page.render('./reports/myaccount.pdf').then(function() {
                console.log('Page Rendered');
                ph.exit();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

These code suppose to print the page(myaccount page) after successful logged in but it prints the login page instead e.g. https://www.example.com/loginpage

Maybe because phantomjs creates another browser session? How can I combine these phantomjs code to existing logging code above?

Thanks for all your time!

Comment: why your login code is separate? how do you expect us to understand it. Drop the whole script as one

Comment: Is that enough @DmitriiG.?

Comment: You are creating another instance of phatomjs inside your logic - that makes no sense. Use one instance and navigate it. Why don't you use the same 'browser' to open your account page after login?

Comment: Hello @DmitriiG. Can you show how to do that? Thanks!